# Using a text box value to fetch the all other details in a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

**Details of the Requirement:**
I have one text box. If i type a pincode in that box, it will go to the controller and match with database and will show the results of list of names in the dropdown list.

**Controller code:**

```
 public ActionResult getPincodeDetail(string pincode)
    {
        var cp = _repository.GetCPByPincode(pincode);
        if (cP == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["CP"] = new SelectList(cP);
        }

        return View("CallCash", cP);
    }
```

**Jquery code:**

```
$('#Pincode').blur(function () {
    var name = $('#Pincode').val();
    var data = 'pincode=' + name;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getPincodeDetail",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            //if (data == "pincode Number exist") {
            window.location = "/Home/getPincodeDetail?pincode=" + name;
            alert("Pincode is available");

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here i don't know how to populate the viewdata result getting from jquery return  into dropdown box.

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("Names","-Select Names-")%>
```

Comment: Drowpdown list is in other redirected page rit?

Comment: I usually does using 'JsonResult' returns selected Name as 'JSON' and it will get as 'data' in 'Onsuccess' of '$.ajax'  we could populate the dropdown using Jquey

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the dropdown list as

```
  Html.DropDownList("Names", new SelectListItem[] {
        new SelectListItem {
            Text = "ABC",
            Value = "a"
        },
        new SelectListItem {
            Text = "XYZ",
            Value = "b"
        }
    }, new {
        @class = "form-control",
        required = "required"
    })
     New With {.class = "form-control", .required = "required"})
```